# Pandas Histogram Plot with Groupby, Axis Control

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, histogram

Trying to plot up mean wind speed by hour-of-the-day (Day-hour) over seasons. This is what I have so far (see figure below). However, I can't seem to get the x-axis to be hour-of-the-day (day-hour) and y-axis to be wind speed.

The data is standard pandas dataframe (see below for the header).

Grateful for the help. Thanks in advance.

Here's a head of the data:

```
time_loc time_utc ObsType Station WindDir WindSpd WindGst T Td MSLP  ... PrecipAccm24h CldAWS VisAWS VisObs doy Year month season                                                                           
2003-01-01 00:06:00 None METAR YSNW 30.0 2.0 3.0 20.0 17.2 1008.6 ... NaN ////// None //// 1 2003 1 DJF
```

Here's my code:

```
time_mean = df['WindSpd'].groupby([lambda x: x.hour,df['season']]).mean()
ax = time_mean.hist(by='season', bins=12, grid=False, figsize=(8,10), layout=(4,1), sharex=True, color='powderblue', zorder=2, rwidth=0.9)
for i,x in enumerate(ax):
        x.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
        x.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
        x.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
        x.tick_params(axis="both", which="both", bottom="off", top="off", labelbottom="on", left="off", right="off", labelleft="on")
        vals = x.get_yticks()
        for tick in vals:
            x.axhline(y=tick, linestyle='dashed', alpha=0.4, color='#eeeeee', zorder=1)
        x.set_xlabel("Day-hour", labelpad=20, weight='bold', size=12)
        if i == 1:
            x.set_ylabel("Wind Speed", labelpad=50, weight='bold', size=12)
        x.yaxis.set_major_formatter(StrMethodFormatter('{x:,g}'))
        x.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=0)
fg = plt.gcf()
fg.savefig(os.path.join(Dplotbase,state,('windSpeed_SeasonHour_'+station+'.png')),bbox_inches = "tight")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the orientation to `horizontal` and invert the y-axis :

```
time_mean = df['WindSpd'].groupby([lambda x: x.hour,df['season']]).mean()
ax = time_mean.hist(by='season', bins=12, grid=False, figsize=(8,10), layout=(4,1), sharex=True, color='powderblue', zorder=2, rwidth=0.9, orientation='horizontal')
for i,x in enumerate(ax):
        x.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
        x.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
        x.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
        x.tick_params(axis="both", which="both", bottom="off", top="off", labelbottom="on", left="off", right="off", labelleft="on")
        vals = x.get_yticks()
        for tick in vals:
            x.axhline(y=tick, linestyle='dashed', alpha=0.4, color='#eeeeee', zorder=1)
        x.set_xlabel("Day-hour", labelpad=20, weight='bold', size=12)
        if i == 1:
            x.set_ylabel("Wind Speed", labelpad=50, weight='bold', size=12)
        x.yaxis.set_major_formatter(StrMethodFormatter('{x:,g}'))
        x.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=0)
fg = plt.gcf().invert_yaxis()
fg.savefig(os.path.join(Dplotbase,state,('windSpeed_SeasonHour_'+station+'.png')),bbox_inches = "tight")
```

Comment: Thanks Ravish. I should have said that simply making the orientation horizontal is not the desired outcome. I'm looking to have day-hour on the x-axis and wind speed on the y-axis; then a histogram for each season. The data is in a pandas dataframe with datetimeindex columns of weather observations and then added columns to represent season, month, year so that the data can be grouped accordingly. I know it is likely something simple I am missing.

Comment: @dpath2o, can you post your additional clarification into the main question so it is clear for everyone on. what the question is. I think it is there but being explicit would be best

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a partial solution. Most importantly I am not after a count of occurences that a histogram reports visually but rather just a quantity. So bar plot is what I should be doing. The following plots wind speed against day-hour with each season coloured a different plot all on the same axes.

```
 sns.catplot(x="hour", y="WindSpd", hue='season', kind="bar", data=df);
```

While this is ok. Really what I want is the mean wind speed across the day-hour for a season plotted on four separate subplots sharing the same x-axis (day-hour).